# Rancher - check from the CLI if a cattle port is taken

Tags: rancher

I have a script that deploys database instances on a dynamic principle by using the rancher CLI commands. Is there a way to check whether a certain port is taken?

F.e. I want to spin up a Postgres server on port 8001 on my cattle. Therefore, first check if the port is taken. If not - start the DB server. Otherwise, try 8002, and so on.

Is there a way for that through the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a service, if you leave out the "Public Host Port" and just specify the "Private Container Port" a random port is assigned for the service. You can later query for this service and fetch the port assigned for this service. For your use case this might be a easier approach than figuring out which port has been consumed.

Find screenshots for UI approach attached:

[image: Created Service]

[image: Random Port assigned]